# Different results from Google Cloud Vision for same image

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku, google-cloud-vision

I have a Flask app that's sending an image to GCV via it's API endpoint (https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate). There are two things that the app does:

- Send the image to Cloud Vision for text extraction
- Resend the same image to Cloud Vision at an angle of positive 89

On my local machine:

- Step 1: returns an output with locale being 'zh-Hant'
- Step 2: returns an output with locale being 'en'

On my remote machine (Heroku):

- Step 1: returns an output with locale being 'en'. Due to this being a different output as compared to step 1 on my local machine, my code fails.

How is it, that for the same image, same API, Cloud Vision returns a different result?